# Uncaught error when trying to embed a Vega chart in Vue + Vuex project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vega-lite

I am trying to use [vega-embed](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed#embed) within a Vue.js (together with vuex for state management) project. Basically the backend serves a Vega json object which is picked up by the frontend via HTTP GET request with a click event. However I have to click twice to get the plot displayed and the first click event always triggers an error "`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '$schema' of null`". Can someone help me debug? Very much appreciated. Details shown below:

The vue component file:

```
<template>
  <button @click.native="fetchCars(); displayVegaPlot()">fetch cars</button>
  <div id="vega-example"></div>
</template>

<script>
  import {default as vegaEmbed} from 'vega-embed'
  import {
  mapState
} from 'vuex'

  export default {
    name: 'VegaExample',
    props: {
      component_msg: String
    },
    methods: {
      fetchCars () {
        this.$store.dispatch('fetchCars')
      },
      displayVegaPlot () {
        vegaEmbed('#vega-example', this.vega_cars, {actions: false})
      }
    },
    computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'vega_cars'
    ])
    }
  }
</script>
```

... and the store js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    error: '',
    vega_cars: null
  },

  mutations: {
    SET_CARS: (state, cars) => {
      state.vega_cars = cars
    },
    SET_ERROR: (state, error) => {
      state.error = error
    }
   }

  actions: {
    fetchCars: (context) => {
      axios.get(`vega_cars`)
        .then(response => context.commit('SET_CARS', response.data))
        .catch(error => context.commit('SET_ERROR', error))
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are neither waiting for the fetch synchronously nor checking your `vega_cars` for a value before using it in `vegaEmbed`. Either `await` your fetch before calling `displayVegaPlot` or don't call it directly and use a watcher and `if vega_cars != null`.

Comment: @TommyF When you referred using `await` were you talking about something like this: `async fetchCars () {
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.$store.dispatch('fetchCars');
          resolve();
        })
        await promise;
        vegaEmbed('#vega-example', this.vega_cars, {actions: false})
      }` I tried but still got the same behaviour...

Comment: That's because your store action is async and immediately returns, not after it received the server response (this is how it should be though). I'm not familiar with vega so it's hard to say what the best solution for adding reactivity would be, but I would either `watch` vega_cars and when it's `!= null` execute your displayVegaPlot method or depending on where else you need vega_cars it might be more appropriate to fetch it locally in this component synchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the comment from @TommyF, after some doc reading I think I figured out the solution (apparently as a newcomer to web app dev and `Vue` I didn't know `Vue` offers a special `watch` facility). So in the component Vue file, instead of declaring a method `displayVegaPlot` to call imperatively, a `watch` can be setup to do the display the Vega plot, as soon as `vega_cars` changes value:

```
    watch: {
    vega_cars: (spec) => {
      console.log('$store.state.vega_cars changed value')
      if (spec) {
        vegaEmbed('#vega-example', spec, {actions: false})
      }
    }
  }
```

and of course `...mapState(['vega_cars'])` needs to be put in `computed`.